# What in the heck is "GPU Bank Flip" in my bios?

Tags: bios

"GPU Bank Flip" under Advanced Chipset Features can be either Enabled or Disabled (default is disabled).

What is it???

Comment: Can you post details of your motherboard and BIOS type and version.

Comment: GPU is Graphics Processing Unit so it might be something to do with the graphics card memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been able to find a thread on [Windows Vista Forums](http://www.vistax64.com/graphic-cards/197042-gpu-bank-flip-2.html) where exactly the same question was posted.

The answer given is:

> GPU Bank Flip; Also known as Graphics Processing Unit, is designed for Crossfire Technology from ATI, certain Circuit Boards which support this is set as Disabled as default for user select for crossfire in later cards, which allow the two ati cards to switch from one unit to the next to use and combine both 1 gb or 512 mb of ram on the cards itself.

So it looks like it allows memory from one graphics card to be used by a second.